# Seguridad de Microservicios Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, cloud, contenedores, security

Tengo tres microservicios diferentes en mi aplicación. La arquitectura se modificó al implementar un Gateway de Spring para el enrutamiento. Dentro de estos cambios la aplicación ejecuta un llamado a otro microservicio (GlobalFilter) para la autenticación y el acceso.

Mi pregunta es. Ahora que estos microservicios no validan los permisos si no que el Gateway se encarga de validarlo con el servicio de Autenticación que seguridad deben tener los microservicios para que solo el GateWay pueda acceder a ellos?
Los servicios estan dockerizados en contenedores.

Comment: Opción simple: el endpoint del gateway sería el único accesible de forma pública y el resto no.

Comment: Como lo dejo privado?

Comment: Si tienes todo en contenedores, puedes tener comunicación entre los servicios usando la red que crea docker y sólo dejar el contenedor del gateway expuesto a través de un nginx como proxy o de alguna otra forma. Hay varias opciones y depende de los requerimientos no funcionales y de como quieras gestionar tus servicios...